# Software Implementation of RAID 10 on a Windows Server 2008 running on Amazon EC2

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, software-raid, amazon-ebs, raid10

Does anyone know of a software implementation of RAID 10 that will work on a Windows Server 2008?  Specifically I'd like to use it on a virtual instance running on Amazon's EC2, connected to EBS disks.

Comment: What is the rationale behind a software RAID10 on a cloud instance?

Comment: I fail to see the reason for RAID-10 on EC2 using EBS disks?  Your main concern is going to be data corruption and that'll still kill a RAID-10 volume.  RAID-0 is technically just as 'secure' as RAID-10 if you want to span multiple EBS volumes on an EC2 instance.

Comment: See http://blog.9minutesnooze.com/raid-10-ebs-data/ for my rationale on RAID 10.

Comment: Hmmm, not quite sure why my question was voted down.  I did extensive research trying to find an answer before I asked it here.  It was only when my research couldn't find a clear answer that I came here.  If you'd care to clarify, I'd love to know so I might improve any future questions I ask here.  Thanks.

Comment: @Thom I suggest quoting part of that article in your question. In particular, mentioning that it's already tested on Linux and now you want to apply it to Windows will give a better feel to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Windows software RAID doesn't support RAID-10. I've never heard of third-party drivers for Windows software RAID and, frankly, I think I'd be afraid of them if they did exist. (They'd have to be debugged and battle-tested before I'd even think of using them...)

Comment: Thank you.  (I agree that unless they had been around for awhile I wouldn't go near 'em).

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to create a RAID-10 configuration in the AWS environment.  AWS is already providing disk redundancy in the EBS layer.

It can be worth creating a RAID-0 configuration.  EBS is notoriously slow and striping your drive across multiple EBS volumes can significantly boost performance.

Comment: Thank you.  At this point, the question is moot, as I've gone with RackSpace.